# Is Bittorrent Sync blocked on networks where "normal" Bitorrent traffic is blocked?

Tags: bittorrent, bittorrent-sync

Let's say I'm on a network that blocks Bittorrent to prevent file sharing of the piracy variety. Would I have any problems using Bittorrent Sync?

Comment: BitTorrent can be blocked in a number of ways. In the case where tracker sites are blocked, BitTorrent Sync are usually unaffected. Do you have more info on the network, such as whether other services are blocked or whitelisted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By experience I can tell you yes, both are blocked.

I don't have a high understanding on this, but I guess both bittorrent and btsync use same ports and configuration.